# How can I shallow copy columns and subarrays of a 2d array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, reference

So I have a 9x9 array representing a Sudoku board. I'd like to be able to break in down into multiple arrays, each referencing the original. For the rows I can simply do

```
int[] row = Board[0];
```

but how can I do this for the columns? I'd also like to do something similar for the nine 3x3 blocks, but once I figure out the columns I should be fine. I realise that 2d arrays are just 1d arrays of 1d arrays, so I will probably have to iterate through, but I can't seem to get anything to work out.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Your question is fairly clear, but it would really help if you gave some sort of example of what final data structure you're looking for.

Comment: I'm just looking for (essentially arbitrary) arrays of integers that all point back to an original 2d array. I'm not really sure if I could elaborate at all

Comment: If you want each array to reference the same underlying data, then that underlying data will need to be objects, and the arrays will contain references to those objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this natively. I mean without iterating over the array. In java you need to specify the `row` index first in order to access the column. So you got two options:

1. Build a utility function.
2. Flip the Array (make rows columns and vise versa).

Note that Sudoko is known to be a Constrained Problem (interesting solving approach).

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int[][] Board=new int[9][9];
        for(int i=0;i<Board.length;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<Board.length;j++)
                Board[i][j]=((i+1)*(j+1));

         for(int i=0;i<Board.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<Board.length;j++)
                 System.out.print(Board[i][j]+" ");
             System.out.println("");
         }
        System.out.println("$$$$");
        int index=1;

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(copyColumn(1, Board)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(flip(Board)[index]));
    }
    public static int[] copyColumn(int index, int[][] Board)
    {
        int[] result=new int[9]; int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<Board.length;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<Board.length;j++)
                if(j==index)
                {
                   result[k]=Board[i][j];
                   k++;
                }
        return result;
    }

    public static int[][] flip(int[][] Board)
    {
        int[][] result=new int[Board.length][Board.length];
        for(int i=0;i<Board.length;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<Board.length;j++)
                result[i][j]=Board[j][i];

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))

```
System.arraycopy(Object source, int StartingPosition, Object destination, int destinationPosition, int length);
```

Or you can do it traditionally with 2 for loops :

Assuming oldArray is 9x9 called oldArray[9][9] and you have 9, 3x3 array called newArrays[9][3][3]

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i+=3) {
   for(int j=0;j<9;j++) {
       newArrays[i][j/3][j%3]=oldarray[i+j/3][j%3];
       newArrays[i+1][j/3][j%3]=oldarray[i+j/3][(j%3)+3];
       newArrays[i+2][j/3][j%3]=oldarray[i+j/3][(j%3)+6];
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but editing the copy will not change the original, and vice-versa. At least as I understand it

Answer (score 0):

You can create an inner class.

```
public class Board {
int[][] board=new int[9][9];
Column column=new Column();

public class Column{
    public int[] getCol(int colIndex){
        int[] col=new int[board.length];
        for(int i=0;i<col.length;i++){
            col[i]=board[colIndex][i];
        }
        return col;
    }

    public void setValue(int rowIndex,int columnIndex,int value){
        board[columnIndex][rowIndex]=value;
    }
}
```

}